# Зависание скрипта при выборке из базы через Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony2, doctrine2

Здравствуйте!

Я использую Symfony2 + Doctrine.
Есть таблица на 20000 записей. 
Суть проблемы вот в чем: по непонятой мне причине происходит зависание скрипта при выборке из этой таблицы. Причем логи mysql чистые, медленных запросов нет.

Схема таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `id1c` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `limit_sales` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `type_of_products` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `exchange_rate_setting_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `description` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `handler` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `art` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
 `price_retail` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
 `image` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `image_width` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `image_height` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `image_big` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `image_big_width` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `image_big_height` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `sort` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `date_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
 `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `IDX_D34A04AD12469DE2` (`category_id`),
 KEY `IDX_D34A04AD49BCFDD9` (`exchange_rate_setting_id`),
 KEY `IDX_PRODUCT_ID1C` (`id1c`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_D34A04AD49BCFDD9` FOREIGN KEY     (`exchange_rate_setting_id`) REFERENCES `setting` (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_D34A04AD12469DE2` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18616 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Код который является источником проблемы:

```
public function search($data)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("p")
        ->select()
        ->where("p.id1c = :data")
        ->setParameter("data", $data);

    $products = $qb->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    return $products;
}
```

В логах приложения появляется лог запроса:

```
[2016-09-20 00:07:43] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT p0_.id AS id_0, p0_.id1c AS id1c_1, p0_.status AS status_2, p0_.limit_sales AS limit_sales_3, p0_.type_of_products AS type_of_products_4, p0_.name AS name_5, p0_.code AS code_6, p0_.description AS description_7, p0_.handler AS handler_8, p0_.art AS art_9, p0_.price AS price_10, p0_.price_retail AS price_retail_11, p0_.image AS image_12, p0_.image_width AS image_width_13, p0_.image_height AS image_height_14, p0_.image_big AS image_big_15, p0_.image_big_width AS image_big_width_16, p0_.image_big_height AS image_big_height_17, p0_.sort AS sort_18, p0_.date_updated AS date_updated_19, p0_.date_created AS date_created_20, p0_.category_id AS category_id_21, p0_.exchange_rate_setting_id AS exchange_rate_setting_id_22 FROM `product` p0_ WHERE p0_.id1c = ? ["00000082457"] []
[2016-09-20 00:07:43] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.id1c AS id1c_2, t0.parent_id1c AS parent_id1c_3, t0.code AS code_4, t0.name AS name_5, t0.description AS description_6, t0.description2 AS description2_7, t0.title AS title_8, t0.meta_h1 AS meta_h1_9, t0.meta_description AS meta_description_10, t0.retail_limit AS retail_limit_11, t0.limit_sales AS limit_sales_12, t0.type_of_products AS type_of_products_13, t0.show_retail_price AS show_retail_price_14, t0.ueprice AS ueprice_15, t0.status AS status_16, t0.sort AS sort_17, t0.parent_id AS parent_id_18 FROM category t0 WHERE t0.id = ? [1621] []
```

Как я понимаю доктрина достает искомый товар, достает категорию, а после зависает. Я не могу понять почему? Меня это просто ставит в тупик.

Как понял что именно в приведенном коде проблема?
Если закомментить строки:

```
    $products = $qb->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

это проблема не возникает.

Буду очень благодарен за любой совет или линк!

---

ADD:
Сущность Product:

```
<?php
namespace Shop\CatalogBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Shop\CatalogBundle\Entity\Repository\ProductRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="`product`")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $id1c;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=2)
     */
    protected $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=10)
     */
    protected $limit_sales;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32)
     */
    protected $type_of_products;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Shop\CoreBundle\Entity\Setting")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="exchange_rate_setting_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(
     *  message = "Необходимо установить текущий курс"
     * )
     */
    protected $exchange_rate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(
     *  message = "Необходимо ввести название товара"
     * )
     * @Assert\Length(
     *  max = 255,
     *  maxMessage = "Длинна названия товара должна быть менее 255 символов"
     * )
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(
     *  message = "Необходимо ввести url-код товара"
     * )
     * @Assert\Length(
     *  max = 255,
     *  maxMessage = "Длинна url-кода должна быть менее 255 символов"
     * )
     */
    protected $code;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $handler;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $art;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2)
     */
    protected $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2)
     */
    protected $price_retail;

    protected $formatted_price;
    protected $formatted_price_retail;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $image;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $image_width;

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $image_height;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $image_big;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $image_big_width;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $image_big_height;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=10)
     */
    protected $sort;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="date_updated")
     */
    protected $updated;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="date_created")
     */
    protected $created;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setCreated(new \Datetime());
        $this->setUpdated(new \Datetime());
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string)$this->getId();
    }

    public function setUpdatedValue()
    {
        $this->setUpdated(new \Datetime());
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     * @return this
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $id1c
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setId1c($id1c)
    {
        $this->id1c = $id1c;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
      * @return string
     */
    public function getId1c()
    {
        return $this->id1c;
    }

    /**
     * @param integer $status
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * @param integer $limitSales
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setLimitSales($limitSales)
    {
        $this->limit_sales = $limitSales;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getLimitSales()
    {
        return $this->limit_sales;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $typeOfProducts
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setTypeOfProducts($typeOfProducts)
    {
        $this->type_of_products = $typeOfProducts;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTypeOfProducts()
    {
        return $this->type_of_products;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $code
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setCode($code)
    {
        $this->code = $code;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCode()
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $description
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $handler
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setHandler($handler)
    {
        $this->handler = $handler;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHandler()
    {
        return $this->handler;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $art
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setArt($art)
    {
        $this->art = $art;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getArt()
    {
        return $this->art;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $price
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        $exchange_rate_setting = $this->exchange_rate;

        if (!($exchange_rate_setting instanceof \Shop\CoreBundle\Entity\Setting))
            return 0;

        if ($this->isUeprice()) {
            return $this->price * $exchange_rate_setting->getValue();
        } else {
            return $this->price;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param string $priceRetail
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setPriceRetail($priceRetail)
    {
        $this->price_retail = $priceRetail;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPriceRetail()
    {
        $exchange_rate_setting = $this->exchange_rate;

        if (!($exchange_rate_setting instanceof \Shop\CoreBundle\Entity\Setting))
            return 0;

        if ($ueprice) {
            return $this->price_retail * $exchange_rate_setting->getValue();
        } else {
            return $this->price_retail;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param string $formatted_price
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setFormattedPrice($formatted_price)
    {
        $this->formatted_price = $formatted_price;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFormattedPrice()
    {
        return $this->formatted_price;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $formatted_price_retail
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setFormattedPriceRetail($formatted_price_retail)
    {
        $this->formatted_price_retail = $formatted_price_retail;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFormattedPriceRetail()
    {
        return $this->formatted_price_retail;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $image
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setImage($image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $imageWidth
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setImageWidth($imageWidth)
    {
        $this->image_width = $imageWidth;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImageWidth()
    {
        return $this->image_width;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $imageHeight
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setImageHeight($imageHeight)
    {
        $this->image_height = $imageHeight;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImageHeight()
    {
        return $this->image_height;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $imageBig
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setImageBig($imageBig)
    {
        $this->image_big = $imageBig;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImageBig()
    {
        return $this->image_big;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $imageBigWidth
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setImageBigWidth($imageBigWidth)
    {
        $this->image_big_width = $imageBigWidth;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImageBigWidth()
    {
        return $this->image_big_width;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $imageBigHeight
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setImageBigHeight($imageBigHeight)
    {
        $this->image_big_height = $imageBigHeight;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImageBigHeight()
    {
        return $this->image_big_height;
    }

    /**
     * @param integer $sort
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setSort($sort)
    {
        $this->sort = $sort;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getSort()
    {
        return $this->sort;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $updated
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setUpdated($updated)
    {
        $this->updated = $updated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdated()
    {
        return $this->updated;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $created
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setCreated($created)
    {
        $this->created = $created;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreated()
    {
        return $this->created;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Shop\CatalogBundle\Entity\Category $category
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setCategory(\Shop\CatalogBundle\Entity\Category $category = null)
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Shop\CatalogBundle\Entity\Category
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Shop\CoreBundle\Entity\Setting $exchangeRate
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setExchangeRate(\Shop\CoreBundle\Entity\Setting $exchangeRate = null)
    {
        $this->exchange_rate = $exchangeRate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Shop\CoreBundle\Entity\Setting
     */
    public function getExchangeRate()
    {
        return $this->exchange_rate;
    }

    /**
     * This method checks if price setted in ue
     * return int
     */
    private function isUeprice()
    {
        $ueprice = true;
        $category = $this->getCategory();

        if ($category instanceof \Shop\CatalogBundle\Entity\Category
            && $category->getUeprice() == 0)
            $ueprice = false;

        $ueprice = $category->getCategoryUeprice();
        var_dump($ueprice);
        die;

        return $ueprice;
    }
}
```

Сущность Category:
https://github.com/GhostSt/Shop/blob/master/src/Shop/CatalogBundle/Entity/Category.php

Сущность Product:
https://github.com/GhostSt/Shop/blob/master/src/Shop/CatalogBundle/Entity/Product.php

Привел ссылки на гитхаб потому что в пост по длинне не влезает.

Полный лог из app/log/dev.log:

```
[2016-09-20 11:24:13] request.INFO: Matched route "ShopCatalogBundle_api_catalog_product_search". {"route_parameters":{"_controller":"Shop\\CatalogBundle\\Controller\\API\\ProductController::searchIndex","_route":"ShopCatalogBundle_api_catalog_product_search"},"request_uri":"http://office.trikatushki.test/app_dev.php/api/catalog/product/search?data=00000082457"} []
[2016-09-20 11:24:13] security.DEBUG: Read existing security token from the session. {"key":"_security_main"} []
[2016-09-20 11:24:13] security.DEBUG: User was reloaded from a user provider. {"username":"GhostSt","provider":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\User\\InMemoryUserProvider"} []
[2016-09-20 11:24:13] php.INFO: The Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveValidator::validateValue method is deprecated in version 2.5 and will be removed in version 3.0. Use the Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface::validate method instead. {"type":16384,"file":"/var/www/office.trikatushki.test/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Validator/RecursiveValidator.php","line":162,"level":28928,"stack":        [{"function":"handleError","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\ErrorHandler","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/office.trikatushki.test/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Validator/RecursiveValidator.php","line":162,"function":"trigger_error"},{"file":"/var/www/office.trikatushki.test/src/Shop/CatalogBundle/Service/ProductSearchService.php","line":35,"function":"validateValue","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Validator\\Validator\\RecursiveValidator","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/office.trikatushki.test/src/Shop/CatalogBundle/Controller/API/ProductController.php","line":23,"function":"search","class":"Shop\\CatalogBundle\\Service\\ProductSearchService","type":"->"},{"function":"searchIndex","class":"Shop\\CatalogBundle\\Controller\\API\\ProductController","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/office.trikatushki.test/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php","line":144,"function":"call_user_func_array"},{"file":"/var/www/office.trikatushki.test/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php","line":64,"function":"handleRaw","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/office.trikatushki.test/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/ContainerAwareHttpKernel.php","line":69,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/office.trikatushki.test/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php","line":185,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerAwareHttpKernel","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/office.trikatushki.test/web/app_dev.php","line":30,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel","type":"->"}]} []
[2016-09-20 11:24:13] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT p0_.id AS id_0, p0_.id1c AS id1c_1, p0_.status AS status_2, p0_.limit_sales AS limit_sales_3, p0_.type_of_products AS type_of_products_4, p0_.name AS name_5, p0_.code AS code_6, p0_.description AS description_7, p0_.handler AS handler_8, p0_.art AS art_9, p0_.price AS price_10, p0_.price_retail AS price_retail_11, p0_.image AS image_12, p0_.image_width AS image_width_13, p0_.image_height AS image_height_14, p0_.image_big AS image_big_15, p0_.image_big_width AS image_big_width_16, p0_.image_big_height AS image_big_height_17, p0_.sort AS sort_18, p0_.date_updated AS date_updated_19, p0_.date_created AS date_created_20, p0_.category_id AS category_id_21, p0_.exchange_rate_setting_id AS exchange_rate_setting_id_22 FROM `product` p0_ WHERE p0_.id1c = ? ["00000082457"] []
[2016-09-20 11:24:13] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.id1c AS id1c_2, t0.parent_id1c AS parent_id1c_3, t0.code AS code_4, t0.name AS name_5, t0.description AS description_6, t0.description2 AS description2_7, t0.title AS title_8, t0.meta_h1 AS meta_h1_9, t0.meta_description AS meta_description_10, t0.retail_limit AS retail_limit_11, t0.limit_sales AS limit_sales_12, t0.type_of_products AS type_of_products_13, t0.show_retail_price AS show_retail_price_14, t0.ueprice AS ueprice_15, t0.status AS status_16, t0.sort AS sort_17, t0.parent_id AS parent_id_18 FROM category t0 WHERE t0.id = ? [1621] []
[2016-09-20 11:24:13] request.INFO: Matched route "ShopCatalogBundle_api_catalog_product_search". {"route_parameters":{"_controller":"Shop\\CatalogBundle\\Controller\\API\\ProductController::searchIndex","_route":"ShopCatalogBundle_api_catalog_product_search"},"request_uri":"http://office.trikatushki.test/app_dev.php/api/catalog/product/search?data=00000082457"} []
```

---

Итог.

Проблему я локализовал и решил. И оказалось она в моей ошибке и недостатке знаний.

В сущности Category настроена self-referenced association, есть поля parent и children.
Метод search я использовал в api и возвращал сериализованный объект.

И получилось, что при нормализации объектов, процесс зацикливался на category->parent->children->category.
Странно что не выводилась ошибка, но тут у меня есть догадка. Так как список children состоит из десятка категорий, нормализатор и не разпознавал зацикливание. Но тут я не уверен.

Очень благодарю всех откликнувшихся за помощь!

Comment: А вы пробовали такой же запрос на базе без ПХП запускать?

Проблемы могут быть: 1) Медленный запрос. 2) Нехватает памяти.

Comment: Пробовал, все ок проходит.

Comment: я сейчас изменил select запроса на 
->select('p.name, p.id1c, p.price, p.price_retail')
и проблема исчезла, но в результате я получаю массив, а не объект.
У меня такое ощущение что доктрина зацикливается. Как-то так: получение товаров -> получение категории товара -> получение товаров категории, среди которых и искомы товар, и все по новой. Возможен ли такой случай?

Comment: Покажите сущности товара и категории?

Comment: без вызова getResult доктрина не дойдет до непосредственно вызова БД. В логах больше ничего нет, просто "дыра" на несколько секунд?

Comment: Привел полный лог запроса, ничего там особенного. Подвисает не на пару секунд, а полность зацикливается, помогает только рестарт апача

Comment: По всей видимости Dоctrine не любит когда наименовние (alias) идентичны. А у тебя с SQL-е есть 2 идентичных alias-а `p0_.name AS name_5` и `t0.name AS name_5`. Возможна проблема здесь. Возможно Doctrine поподает в вечный цикл когда две похожих alias-а поподаеться.

Comment: По мне необходимо очередь выводимых колонок изменить. Думаю если в сущности Product измени местами свойства `name` и `type_of_products`. Так же измени местами их геттерары и сеттеры. Возможно и в селекте они поменяються местами. Или вручную укажи все колонки которые в `select()` изменив положение `name`.

Answer (score 1):

Измените в запросе `select()` на `select('p')` или убери его вообще.